# What does number of inches per day squared mean?

Tags: acceleration

To give some context to this question, the Pioneer spacecraft were decelerating by:

> 300 inches per day squared

http://www.nasa.gov/topics/solarsystem/features/pioneer_anomaly.html

I cannot find an explanation of why the deceleration would be described like this.

Brian

Comment: Those are just units that are closer to average-day magnitudes. It is hard to imagine what an acceleration of $-0.9$ nm/s$^2$ should be, but 300 inches/day$^2$ is much easier to understand. Both are units of acceleration (or deceleration).

Comment: I think the problem is in parsing the English - is it supposed to be read as (inches/day) squared, or inches per (day) squared. Of course, for acceleration it is (unit length) per (unit time)$^{2}$, which is one of the (and at least for this native American speaker the normal) ways to parse it out.

Comment: It's hard to find units which make this any easier to visualise, I think: it's getting on for 3km/y per day

Comment: And quite typically for Stack Exchange it gets the obligatory down vote.... tut tut, how does he not already know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly, this means that if the spacecraft travels 1000 inches on the first day, it will slow down enough to travel only 700 inches on the second day, and then slow down enough more to travel only 400 inches on the third day, and then slow down enough more to travel only 100 inches on the fourth day.

In other words, it takes the spacecraft one day to slow down by an additional 300 inches per day.  Or in other words, the spacecraft slows down by 300 inches per day, and does this every day.  Or in other words, it slows down by 300 inches per day, per day.  Instead of saying "per day, per day", we say "per day squared".

Comment: To be sure, Pioneer 10 is still travelling at about 12 km/sec relative to the sun.  This micro-deceleration is just a blip, but scientists were searching for an explanation in a number of different areas.